# FileReader and JSON objects not defined in ie11

Tags: javascript, json, filereader, internet-explorer-11

Whenever trying to open a page running a javascript code using FileReader and JSON upon page initialization, ie11 reports "FileReader is not defined", and later "JSON is not defined". The head of HTML file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>LogViewer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slick.grid.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Everything works fine in FF and Chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you are accessing your site in Compatibility Mode. FileReader and JSON are supported starting with IE10. Check your IE compatibility settings. And follow the Jan Schejbal's advice on meta tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` as the first tag of the header to be sure. IE loves to go to compatibility mode even if a HTML5 doctype is present under certain circumstances (especially on intranet files when the computer is in a domain).

You can use the developer tools (F12) to check what mode you are running in.

Comment: Is there a solution if I absolutely HAVE to use content="IE=9"?