# line: 654 error: 'FileReader' is undefined internet explorer 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

[image]Hi Im trying to preview image before uploading using `<Input>` but gives me error on FileReader(). I thought it is supported on the IE10?

```
function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
    };
};
```

Comment: [`FileReader` is supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=FileReader) in IE10. Are there any useful lines in the browser console (F12)?

Comment: On developer Tools: Breaking on JavaScript runtime error-'FileReader is Undefined.'

Comment: vcsjone thanks. its just a title  the code is the one i have there

Comment: Its funny  when i created new Asp.net Project and i test it on it, it wok,the point is in my solution i have so may projects and maybe somewhere the compatibity issue or maybe in Web.config? any idea

Comment: Is your browser running in a different mode? My bet is you have a header set that is putting it into IE9 mode.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577007/filereader-and-json-objects-not-defined-in-ie11

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this in as the first tag in your header:

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Beware of tags like content="IE=9".

Comment: Well I ended up using Devexpress File Object. thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found some code to preview image before upload it. i think this will improve your code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
      var dataURL = reader.result;
      var output = document.getElementById('output');
      output.src = dataURL;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  };

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
<img id='output'>
</body>
</html>
```

you can see [more example here](http://www.javascripture.com/FileReader)