# Leaflet and IE11 JSON not defined error

Tags: json, leaflet

I'm using some REST services and leaflet to display fire perimeters on a map.  Here's the URL: http://www.wrh.noaa.gov/mfr/sa/testmap.php

It works nicely on FF, has some errors in Chrome, and it really doesn't display at all on IE11.  I get a "JSON not defined" error on the console.

Does anyone know why this is happening, or better yet, how I can fix it?

Thanks for any help,
S

Comment: Looks like you a need a `meta` tag - take a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20577113/1238737

Comment: Excellent!  This works perfectly.  Thank you.